# Controlling several experimental setups through one remote computer

Tags: labview

I am completely new here and I want to start using LabView in order to control several experimental setups, improve my work environment and start automation of my experiments.
I have several experimental setups in different labs. Each has a PC that controls the pumps, sensors and valves. I would like to use LabView in order to monitor and automate the setups.

I am wondering if it is possible to run LabView on my office computer which controls the setups through the lab computers. This would be very practical because my PC is much more powerful and I can do alot of work from my office. Maybe someone can give me a hint if there is a way to do this or not.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's the software that runs on the lab PCs at the moment? Do you want to replace that software, or just automate it in some way? The answer to your question is yes, it should be possible, but at the moment it's to broad to give much more of an answer.

Comment: The PCs run either LabView (with limited capability) or a bunch of different softwares for the different devices. In the first step I want to setup LabView in order to have one platform for control and data collection. Maybe Remote Desktop would be the easiest solution. Automation comes much later.

Comment: It sounds like there is lots of potential for you to use LabVIEW here, but as a beginner you need to start small and work up to it. Try the LabVIEW tutorials - and courses if you can - and look at the examples and at the code for your existing LabVIEW programs. Maybe try reimplementing one of the other control programs in LabVIEW, if you can find the information you need about how to interface to the equipment. Eventually, maybe you can look at how to introduce inter-application communication to coordinate the data collection and analysis, for example.